# Weather forecast by pushing data from an old array into a new array using angularjs and openweathermap

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, openweathermap

Hi guys I've been struggling to make this thing work the whole weekend, but I can't seem to get my head around it. What I'm trying to achieve is to pick weatherdata from an array using an openweathermap api and then push this data into a new array. my problem is that I want to make this work like a 24 hour forecast that always start at 06:00 AM the next day, therefore I only want to push the data that exists within this 24 hour interval. But as I said I can't seem to get this to work.

Here's my code:

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="weatherApp" ng-controller="weatherController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in forecastArray">
            {{x.dt_txt}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```js
var app = angular.module('weatherApp', []);

app.controller('weatherController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.units = 'metric';
    $scope.apiId = '...'; //My api key  


    $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?', { params : {
        q : "london",
        units : $scope.units,
        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
        APPID: $scope.apiId
    }}).success(function(response){
        $scope.data = response.list;
    });

    $scope.forecastArray = []; //new array
    var dtStart = new Date(...); //Have no clue how to define this object...
    var dtEnd = new Date(+new Date(dtStart) + 86400000); //dtStart + 24 hours

    $scope.data.forEach(function(item){
        var date = new Date(item.dt); //defining the dt property in data as a new dateobj
        if(date > dtStart && date < dtEnd){
            $scope.foreCastArray.push(item);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you basically ask how to create a `Date` object for tommorow 6am.

First create the `Date` object for tommorow using

```
var today = Date();
var tommorow = Date();
tommorow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
```

Then set the hours and minutes correctly.
Using `Date.setHours(hour,min,sec,millisec)`:

```
tommorow.setHours(6,0,0,0);
```

That should work.

Comment: Your welcome! You can mark the answer if you like so other users know it helped you.